# how to wget continue previous loop if url return 404 ? bash

Tags: linux, bash, wget

i am trying to write a script to auto download some pictures online.

How can I break inside loop when k returns 404 and continue the previous loop ?

Here is my code:

```
for i in {1..50}; 
do
for k in {1..100}; 
do
wget http://www.magga.com/files?cat=$i&id=$k
done
```

thanks

Comment: By "continue", do you mean "retry"? *Which* loop do you want to affect?

Comment: ex. the loop will try..
http://www.magga.com/files?cat=1&id=1
http://www.magga.com/files?cat=1&id=2
...
http://www.magga.com/files?cat=1&id=20 return 404 , 
then continue http://www.magga.com/files?cat=2&id=1 ..and so on

Comment: looks like you want to do something like `[ $? -eq 8 ] && break` will terminate the inner loop if wget exits with a "Server issued an error response" response code.

Comment: yes, i want to terminate the inside loop if wget file return 404, then continue the code

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Did you actually try what I suggested?

Comment: sorry, i am not sure what to do. i am new with wget..could you give me sample code to execute the following above task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wget`'s output is sent to stderr including `404` error.
You can check if the output string contains `404 Not Found` and then exit from the innermost loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..50}; do
    for k in {1..100}; do
        ret=$(wget http://www.magga.com/files?cat=${i}&id=${k} 2>&1)
        if [[ "$ret" =~ 404\ Not\ Found ]]; then
            break   # exit from current "k" loop and continues with next "i"
        fi
    done
done
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having wget write to file, store the output in a variable. For example:

```
check=$(wget -O - http://www.magga.com/files?cat=$i&id=$k)
```

stores the output in $check. If the length of $check is zero -- you can get the length via ${#check}, break the loop. Otherwise write $check to a file.